# SSIS Derived Column Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

When I do I Derived Column Transformation Editor I'm trying to replace a column with something else and I can't get the syntax right.

My expression

```
[Column]= "11-1-2013"
```

It always tells me the syntax is wrong for this.  I tried apostrophe's as well to no avail.  Whats the right syntax for assignment in this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a column and you want to assign the value 11-1-2013 to it.  If that is the case then just put "11-1-2013" into the expression (don't include the **[Column] =**).  For example, if your column is named aColumn and you want to set the value to 11-1-2013, then use the following values in the Derived Column Transformation Editor

```
Derived Column Name - aColumn  
Derived Column      - Replace 'aColumn'
Expression          - "11-1-2013"
```